# use udev to reload bluetooth service when dongle is plugged in

Tags: linux, usb, bluetooth, udev

I have tried to create a file /etc/udev/rules.d/97-bluetooth-input.rules with in it:

```
KERNEL=="event*", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", DEVPATH=="/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3/1-7.1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/usr/bin/systemctl restart bluetooth.service"
```

I also tried omitting DEVPATH but nothing seems to work.

After changes I do `sudo udevadm control -R` then unplug the dongle and plug it back in but the bluetooth service isn't restarted.

With `udevadm monitor -u` I see the following when I plug the dongle in:

```
UDEV  [456580.937864] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [456580.942751] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3/1-7.1.3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [456580.943739] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3/1-7.1.3:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [456580.945729] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3/1-7.1.3:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [456580.947046] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3/1-7.1.3:1.3 (usb)
UDEV  [456580.948077] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3/1-7.1.3:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [456580.948187] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3/1-7.1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0 (bluetooth)
UDEV  [456580.949265] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3/1-7.1.3:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [456580.950853] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3/1-7.1.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/rfkill38 (rfkill)
UDEV  [456580.952866] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3/1-7.1.3:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [456580.954560] bind     /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7.1/1-7.1.3 (usb)
```

What am I missing please?